# Converting data types from one database table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I did a bulk insert on a large text file that was an update for an existing database that I had.  I ran into all kinds of trouble with truncation errors so I just set everything to `varchar(max)`.  Now that everything is in SQL Server I'd like to convert the data types from database b, to those of database a.  If both databases had the same table and field names, what are some methods of getting this done?  Or would it be best to have a pre-existing script you run after import that's 'hardcoded'

Comment: Did you need to set everything to `varchar(max)`? Surely you only needed to set the length to max for the columns that were already varchar, all other datatypes would have probably been fine and you wouldn't be in this mess! Is reimporting a possibility? It will probably be less work.

Comment: Does your copy DB have any keys, relationships, indexes, etc?

Comment: yes, it's all indexed properly with the proper keys

Comment: @Bridge, i didn't HAVE to set everything to varchar(max) but i was handed the data in an unnormalized manner and there were 50+ columns so I went for expediency.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie, I'm not sure how you have keys and such if everything is a varchar(max).

Comment: @TimLehner so I have an established database with all the keys and indexes on it.  I bulk inserted this gig text file into a different database, just to make sure I didn't mess anything up.  Only the denormalized data are varchar(max).  My 'real' database isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this and modify the result and execute it

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql=''
select 
    @sql=@sql+'Alter table '+table_name+' alter column '+column_name+' '+cast(data_type as varchar(100))+
    case when data_type like '%char%' then '(' else '' end +cast(coalesce(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,'' ) as varchar(100))+
    case when data_type like '%char%' then ')' else '' end+';' 
 from 
    information_schema.columns
where 
    table_name='test'
print @sql
```

Comment: i haven't written any dynamic sql yet :)

Comment: this is what i was going for.  more of a pseudo code way of thinking about it.

Comment: Ok. There are some cases where you need dynamic sql

Comment: Yeah, I'm just a beginner and I'm not quite comfortable with writing it yet.  thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a view of the table your looking to pull from and just cast() the columns you need to change to the data types you need to change them to. Then you can just do all of your inserts off of that View in the appropriate data type. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving data from one sql server database to another you could use [Atlantis Interactive Data Inspector](http://www.atlantis-interactive.co.uk/products/datainspector/default.aspx).  If you don't want to do that, you can script out the table in  database a then paste `ALTER TABLE [table] ALTER COLUMN` before every column and run in on database b.

Comment: this way my fall back.  i was thinking of something like `case when a.column1 = a.column2` statements that will run the cast function.